# Cannot auto-complete c++ in vs code

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Hey I recently started using vs code and am having a really weird issue. where my code won't auto complete. I have installed the c/c++ extension and have the "c_cpp_properties.json" file containning the following

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Before you ask I have copied proper include path to "/usr/include" I just did a really simple test I wrote 1 line

"VkInstance instance;"
It compiled and ran fine but whenever I start to type VkInstance It never comes up as auto complete. Moreover weirdly some stuff auto completes fine and other stuff doesn't for example "vkCreateInstance" shows up as i'm typing it. Perhaps I'm missing something or doing something wrong would like some feedback

Thanks!

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main()
{
    VkInstance instance;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation (or bug?) of VSCode's code completion feature. The Vulkan header wraps the typdefs for all handles (like VkInstance, VkFence, etc.) in a Macro and it looks like VSCode can't handle this.

E.g. this:

> VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkInstance)

Won't autocomplete, but if you replace the macro by hand to get this:

> typedef struct VkInstance_T* VkInstance;

Auto-Completion works.

If this is a bug (just had a quick look at this), it may be worth reporting over at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues